# Having problem with foreach: Giving me warning

Tags: php, arrays

I have this:

```
foreach ($country as $value){
```

The contents of $country using print_r is this:

```
Array
```

However, when I print_r all of POST variables it shows me country as single array rather than an array within an array as the above suggests?

```
Array ( 
    [entry] => http://www.google.com
    [SelectLocation] => Canada
    [country] => Array ( 
        [0] => AL
        [1] => AS 
    )
    [type] => country
    [destination] => http://yahoo.co.uk
    [default] => http://yahoo.com
    [loginsubmit] =>
)
```

What's going on?

Thanks all

### Update

I have done this:

```
$country = sanitize($_POST['country']);
```

So the contents of $_POST['country'] is $country, right?!

Comment: What you mention in your update should work just fine.

Comment: @Nick - probably a function to sanitize user input (protect against sql injection, etc.)

Comment: @Eric Doesn't mean that is a given.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, my sanitize function was terrible. I have sovled the problme. That function seemed to discard arrays since it only checks strings! Sorry everyone. :)

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you were expecting register_globals to be on (which would create your $country variable from the POST) but that setting is not on.

So, your options are:

1. Use $_POST['country'] instead of $country (good idea).
2. Turn on register_globals ([bad idea](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)!)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't need `$_POST['country']` instead of just plain `$country`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok .. lets get this straight

You have a $_POST Array like this?

```
Array ( 
   [entry] => http://www.google.com
   [SelectLocation] => Canada 
   [country] => Array ( 
                        [0] => AL 
                        [1] => AS 
               ) 
   [type] => country 
   [destination] => http://yahoo.co.uk 
   [default] => http://yahoo.com 
   [loginsubmit] => 
)
```

Which you are trying to send through a foreach loop:

```
foreach($_POST['country'] as $value)
{
    echo $value . "<br>";
}
```

and should output

```
AL
AS
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Where is `$country` coming from?  Are you assuming that `$_POST` variables are auto-extracted into the current scope?  Because they are not.  Perhaps you want this instead?

```
foreach ( $_POST['country'] as $value) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem here:

```
$country = $_POST['country'];
foreach ($country as $value){
    echo $value . '<br />';
}
```

If you're confused because the $_POST array contains an array for the country key, the explanation is square brackets after the HTML name attribute, which ensures that PHP gets the collection as an array:

```
<select name="country[]" multiple="multiple">
...
</select>
```

or perhaps:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="US"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="UK"/>
```